# Best way to compare classification output between different locations

Tags: machine-learning, classification, k-means, correlation, similarity

I ran a neural network for 20+ different locations across the United States. At each location I have a list of their predictions in an array. This looks something like this...

```
loc1 = [2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, ... 2]
loc2 = [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, ....1]
...
```

I am trying to find a way to see what locations predicted the most similarly. i.e. What locations arrays and the most like others.

My first idea was to use k-means clustering. However, when trying to find the appropriate number of clusters using an elbow plot, an elbow doesn't appear and instead it's just a straight line like this...
[image]

My next idea was to calculate the correlation between all the locations and only looking at correlations that were >0.25. However, none of the locations were greater than 0.25 which makes me think I need to reevaluate how to find locations that predict similarly. Should I take this a different direction?

note: I am coding this all in Python

Answer (score 0):

Reducing 0.25 to something like 0.15 would help you find the similar predictions. Similar prediction arrays have high correlation. If you can get a set of arrays with correlation just above 0.15 (for example), then you have found similar predictions. Hope this helps.